# Service and MediaPlayer - Control screen rotation and App exit

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-mediaplayer, status

SOLVED - See answer.

I'm dealing with an app that uses a service for playing music with the MediaPlayer class.

I'm having problem with screen rotation and when I leave the app. I lose the reference or state of the MediaPlayer object or the service itself. Been working so many hours with this that not really know what is wrong.

I start and bind to the service in Activity's `onResume`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        super.onResume();
    }
```

I get the reference to the service with a `ServiceConnection`:

```
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection=new ServiceConnection()
    {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder)
        {
            service=((MusicService.MyBinder)binder).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
        {
            service=null;
        }
    };
```

At this point I can call any method from my service: `service.playMusic();` and works fine.

I unbind in `onDestroy`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is my Service class:

```
public class MusicService extends Service
{
    private final IBinder binder=new MyBinder();
    private MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        player=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tumbler);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.setVolume(80, 80);

        return binder;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MusicService getService()
        {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }

    public void play()
    {
        player.start();
        Log.d("MUSIC SERVICE", "play!");
    }
}
```

**So, problems are:**

- When I exit, the service and music keeps playing. I want to stop it. If I enter the app again, same service is launched again and the music is playing twice. I want to stop it.
- When I rotate the screen, the MediaPlayer keeps playing (as I want) but I can't call anymore pause(), start() and so on because it state has changed (I get the message ' MediaPlayer﹕ pause called in state 8' and `MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0').

Please, need some help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I think I got it.

I had a mess in my mind (and code) but finally it's working.
*If this is not the correct way to do this, please let me know.*

**The first of my problems was**: When the App exits the Service wasn't destroyed and the MediaPlayer was playing until I force-close the App. If I didn't force-close, on App relaunch I had 2 MediaPlayers playing simultaneously and so on.

**Cause**: I was not terminating my Service manually.
**Solution**: On Activity's `onDestroy()`, call `unbindService()` and `stopService()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();

    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class));
}
```

**The second problem was**: When the screen was rotated I lost the MediaPlayer's object reference, and music was out of control because I couldn't access the object.
**Cause**: Bad design. I was setting up the MediaPlayer into Service's onBind() method. **Thanks to @kcoppock**. He noticed that. So, when the screen was rotated, Activity's onCreate() was called and I have bindService() on it, causing the creation of the new MediaPlayer object without even cleaning up the former instance.
**Solution**: Just move out that code to another part that is not called automatically, and call it manually once, when the App starts, and not every time that Activity is recreated by configChanges.

So, basically that is how I fixed it, hope it may help to other users.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    player=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.tumbler);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(80, 80);

    return binder;
}
```

You're re-initializing the `MediaPlayer` every time you bind to the service and never stopping the previous instance. Don't start the media in `onBind()`, wait for a command to the service to start/stop the media player. Services outlive the Activity (that's what they're designed for) so it's no surprise that it keeps playing after the Activity is destroyed. Unless you specifically told it otherwise, that's the expected behavior. If you're wanting a media player that just keeps going while the Activity is open, you might want to look into using a headless Fragment to keep a retained Fragment that can manage the `MediaPlayer` for you in `onCreate()`/`onDestroy()`.

Comment: in his case he didn't start the Service (he just called bindService with BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag) so when the Activity is destroyed the Service is destroyed too

Comment: Thanks for reply =). You were right that was creating multiple instances. I fixed that, but when I rotate the screen, the reference of the MediaPlayer becomes null and I get the corresponding exception. Also, I tried to stop the player when the service is destroyed (onDestroy) and it works when I exit the app but also when I rotate the screen. I only want to stop when exit.

Comment: Well, I fixed too the null reference by returning START_STICKY and call startService() before bind. So now only I need to know how keep playing when rotate but NOT when exit. Please help.